# Python3 : Parsing packet header with struct library

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sockets, networking

Recently, I've been looking into PyMySql source code. Just to wanna learn what's going on between Mysql server and client under the hood.

And there's this `_read_packet` method.

```
def _read_packet(self, packet_type):
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
    
    btrl, btrh, packet_number = struct.unpack("<HBB", packet_header)
    bytes_to_read = btrl + (btrh << 16)
```

This basically tells me that

1. Read first 4 bytes from the server response. (And this 4 bytes are packet header)`b'N\x00\x00\x00'`
2. Unpack the packet header with 'one unsigned short(2bytes), two unsigned char(1byte)'
   `b'N\x00'`, `'\x00'`, `'\x00'`
3. Then you can get the starting point of the payload(`bytes_to_read`).

Here's the thing I couldn't understand:

[image]

According to this picture, first 4 bytes match to the picture's first row.

and If I put together the result gotten from unpacking,

- btrl = Version, IHL(Header Length), Type of Service(TOS)   (First 2 bytes : `unsigned short`
- btrh = Half of the Total length    (the next 1 byte `unsigned char`)
- packet_number = The other half of the Total length    (The last 1 byte `unsinged char`)

Is this the right match? I think something is missing and got the wrong matches.

and after I debug the variables:
btrl is 78, btrh is 0, packet_number is 0

What does the btrl, btrh stand for?

Lastly, How can "`btrl + (btrh << 16)`" be the `bytes_to_read`?

I mean why 16? What happen if the number is 8, 32 or 64?

Can you guys explain this like talking to your nephew? :)